# How to take derivative?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Find a curve passing through (0,0) and (1,1) that is an extremal of the function

$${\rm J}\left(x,y,y'\right)=
\int_{0}^{1}\left[ y'^{\,2}\left(x\right ) + 12\,x\,{\rm y}\left(x\right)\right]\,{\rm d}x$$

I am very confused how to take the derivative:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right) = 0.$$

I got $12x+12y*2y^2=0$, which doesn't seem right. Could someone write out the differentiation?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y,y')=y'^2+12xy$, so you want $12x+(2y')'=0$.

Comment: What about the d/dx part, how is that found? And why is the last term not just 2y'?

Comment: Because of the $d/dx$!  :)

Comment: Is this the second derivative or something?

Comment: Well, yeah! That's what second derivative means.

Comment: But if we have $y'^2$, then the derivative is 2y', and where does the x play in here?

Comment: You need to study the derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: @TedShifrin, Any chance for assistance here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066495/minimization-of-variational-total-variation-tv-deblurring